# Changing network ip in a bash script started from a NFS-mounted folder

Tags: linux, bash, ip, nfs

I wrote a simple Bash script to change the network address of a Linux Host:

```
#!/bin/sh
REMOTE_HOST=192.168.2.127   # Default Host address
NEW_IP=192.168.30.33        # New IP I want to set
NEW_GW=192.168.30.1         # New Gateway I want to set

sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.1     # Moving to the right network...
#ping $REMOTE_HOST -c 3            # I can correctly ping the host here...

ssh-copy-id root@${REMOTE_HOST} > /dev/null   # ...for my comfort...

# Setting the network with new values for the IP addr and the GW...
COMMAND="sed -i 's@address *\\([0-9.]\\+\\)@address ${NEW_IP}@' /etc/network/interfaces\
      && sed -i 's@gateway *\\([0-9.]\\+\\)@gateway ${NEW_GW}@' /etc/network/interfaces"

ssh root@${REMOTE_HOST} $COMMAND
# done!

# Now restart the network services:
ssh root@${REMOTE_HOST} "/etc/init.d/networking restart &" &   # (Note the 2nd '&' !!!)

# Come back to my old IP
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.30.10
sudo route add default gw 192.168.30.1
```

This script works almost perfectly but:

1) If I run it from my home folder, no problems; if I run it from a NFS shared folder the script hangs for a minute or two before to end correctly

2) If I omit the second '&' when restarting the network on the host the command never returns...

The questions are:

1) What causes the long wait (NFS, different IP address, different gateway)? And is it possible to workaround it?

2) Why it happens? How could I avoid it?

Thanks for any kind of help and sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

You're restarting networking services, which drops all active connections.

Bash reads the file you're running line by line. Since NFS is a Network File System, this will terminate the connection to the file. So the system waits (can't actually) with executing the lines after `networking restart` until the connection is re-established.

Instead, you should first make a local copy of the entire script and then run it locally.
You could also code a script for that ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I agree with your description of the process: What I really don't understand is: Why does it work anyway, even with a long wait? Once terminated connection to the script-file, this cannot reset the networks on my machine... who does this action, letting the script to end itself?

Comment: You're letting the script write a new IP to `/etc/network/interfaces`, which will reset the network connection to take the new IP in use. You're probably lucky that your NFS share still allows a connection to the new IP because you're still in its subnet.